# Receiving Error Code 307 while running Jmeter scripts behind proxy

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-307

I have to conduct a PT on a mobile application.
The recording was done from personal laptop where we didn't face any problem.

However, when we transfer the PT scripts to the testing network, we are facing the following error every time we run it:-

### Error in Sample Result:-

Response code: 307
Response message: Authentication Required

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 307 Authentication Required
Date: Mon, 19 Oct 2015 09:53:21 GMT
Proxy-Connection: close
Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en

### Error in Response Data:-

Authentication Required

Kindly help us as we have very less time to provide the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several round of brainstorming, I have found out the solution.
Just ensure that the HTTP Request Implementation is set to "JAVA" and the "Redirect Automatically" is set checked-in.

The Scripts will run only for this combination.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're running JMeter behind the proxy you can pass credentials via command-line arguments like:

   ```
   -H, --proxyHost <argument>
       Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
   -P, --proxyPort <argument>
       Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
   -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
       Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
   -u, --username <argument>
       Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
   -a, --password <argument>
   ```

   see [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) for other keys which might be useful
2. It may be internal application under test authentication challenge, for instance it expects certain [HTTP Header](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) or [Cookie](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar). The easiest way to check it is recording the same actions one more time and inspect 2 JMX files for any differences. If they are - they need to be correlated.

Comment: We are including the steps which is mentioned in point no. 1.... For point no. 2, we cannot perform the recording as it is a remote system and wifi connection is not available for the mobile application recording. .... Kindly share some more information on what might be checked in HTTP Header or Cookie.